# Отступ между View-компонентами в ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, android-constraintlayout

Вопрос достаточно простой, правда сам пока не нашёл на него ответ.

Представим простенький макет с корневым ViewGroup-компонентом ConstraintLayout. Внутри нашего внешнего контейнера мы расположим 2 кнопки, которые условно назовём `btn_1` и `btn_2`.

Программно создадим между этими View-компонентами горизонтальную цепочку при помощи метода `createHorizontalChain(int leftId, int leftSide, int rightId, int rightSide, int[] chainIds, float[] weights, int style)`, который принадлежит классу `android.support.constraint.ConstraintSet`.

Затем я выровнял кнопки по ширине при помощи свойства `weight` для каждого из `View`-элементов.

**А теперь сам вопрос**. Мне нужно настроить отступ между самими кнопками уже после того, как они находятся в цепочке (использовал **CHAIN_SPREAD**) и к ним применены веса (соотношение 1:1). Какой метод мне может в этом помочь? К примеру, мне необходимо установить расстояние между кнопками равное 15 dp.

**P.S.** Всё это необходимо сделать программно. В XML это сделать довольно-таки легко, а вот программно почему-то не получается.